# Hurewicz theorem proof: show path classes are equal modulo commutator subgroup

Tags: algebraic-topology, proof-explanation

I am trying to understand Rotman's proof of the Hurewicz Theorem for $n=1$ (Theorem 4.29).

Let $\phi:\pi_1(X,x_0)\to H_1(X)$ be the Hurewicz map and suppose $X$ is path connected. Then the theorem says that $\phi$ is a surjection whose kernel is $\pi_1(X,x_0)'$, the commutator subgroup. For simplicity, we denote the fundamental group as $\pi$ and its commutator subgroup as $\pi'$.

My confusion is on the second part, namely that $\ker\phi=\pi'$.

Now, I understand why $\pi'\subseteq\ker\phi$. So suppose $[\gamma]\in\ker\phi$. If we identify $\gamma$, as a closed path, with the cycle $\gamma$, then I understand that we can find 1-simplices $\tau_{ij}$ such that $$\gamma=\sum n_i(\tau_{i0}-\tau_{i1}+\tau_{i2}).\tag{*}$$ (Basically, we write $\gamma$ as $\partial_2\sum n_i\tau_i$ for 2-simplices $\tau_i$ and let $\tau_{ij}$ denote the $j$-th face of $\tau_i$.) Also, note that $\gamma$ is a basis element, so it is equal to $\tau_{pq}$ for some fixed $p,q$.

Path connectedness of $X$ lets us construct paths $\lambda_i$, $\mu_i$, and $\nu_i$, which go from $x_0$ (the base point of the fundamental group) to $\tau_{i0}(e_0)$, $\tau_{i1}(e_1)$, and $\tau_{i2}(e_0)$, respectively. If any of these three endpoints are equal to $x_0$, then we make sure that the corresponding path is the constant at $x_0$. And if we have $\tau_{i0}(e_0)=\tau_{j0}(e_0)$, then we pick $\lambda_i=\lambda_j$ (and similarly for $\mu,\nu$, of course).

[image]

So now we can define the following path classes in $\pi$:
\begin{align*}
L_{i0}&=[\lambda_i*\tau_{i0}*\mu_i^{-1}],\\
L_{i1}&=[\nu_i*\tau_{i1}*\mu_i^{-1}],\\
L_{i2}&=[\nu_i*\tau_{i2}*\lambda_i^{-1}].
\end{align*}

Now we apply the substitution principle. In particular, this principle tells us that if $\tau_{ij}=\tau_{mn}$ implies $\overline{L_{ij}}=\overline{L_{mn}}$, then we can basically substitute $\overline{L_{pq}}$ for $\gamma$ and $\bar L$'s for corresponding $\tau$'s in $(*)$. Here, the bar represents coset mod $\pi'$.

**Now here is my problem:** How do we know that we can apply the substitution principle here?

So as a concrete example, let's say $\tau_{i1}=\tau_{j0}$. Then we would like to show that $[\nu_i*\tau_{i1}*\mu_i^{-1}]$ and $[\lambda_j*\tau_{j0}*\mu_j^{-1}]$ differ by an element of $\pi'$, unless I'm missing something. Can someone let me know: Am I missing something, or is there supposed to be an obvious way to apply the substitution principle?